# Why is the & operator used after using scanf?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
char string = "default";
printf("The default String is: %s", &string);
scanf("%s", &string);
printf("You entered: %s", &string);
```

The first printf statement prints out &string as `X(?_?`. The second printf, after the scanf statement prints out the string I entered.

Since the &var operator means "memory address of var", then why does &string print out the string entered? Why do I get a segmentation fault, when I attempt to use just "string"?

Comment: Your code is absolutely riddled with *undefined behaviour*: it works by accident. A good answer will be quite a long one. Let's wait for it.

Comment: The very fitst line is not valid C. It's hard to reason about subsequent lines because of that.

Comment: Voting to close, as paying attention to compiler warnings would have obviated the need for this question entirely.

Comment: It's hard to believe that the first line even compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `string` as a single character but you fill it with a string. This invokes undefined behavior. You should change your code to :

```
char string [20] = "default";   //20 is random, you should use the maximum length of the input you may have
printf("The default String is: %19s", string);
scanf("%s", string);
printf("You entered: %s", string);
```

---

In general, `scanf` needs to take a memory address as an argument, and in the code above, `string` is  a memory address. You can read more about `scanf` in [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

Comment: `char *string = "default";` would be more correct. The assignment changes the pointer and the allocated 20 chars become inaccessible. The program works in both cases, though.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi Have you tried it?

Comment: Your syntax for declaring an array of character is incorrect. You should also use the `"%19s"` format for `scanf` to not write out of bounds of the array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg will it make `scanf` more likely to succeed, or less?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I forgot about that, sorry. Edited, thanks.

Comment: Ah, and you are doing a `scanf` into `string`! You are using the storage of the constant string. This is wrong

Comment: @AhmadWabbi but this is what the OP wants to do. He wants to read on the same storage.

Comment: @Marievi You are right

Comment: Yes, OP code is messed up, but "`string` as a single character but you fill it with a string".  Instead `string` is assigned a narrowed version of the address of the string literal.  _That_ is not UB.

Comment: People have strong feelings about `gets()`, but when an answer with `scanf("%s", string);` comes up, they be upvotin. SMH.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char chomp(char* s, char c){
    size_t l = strlen(s);
    if (!l) return 0;
    return s[l-1] = s[l-1]==c ? '\0' : s[l-1];
}

int main(){
    char string[] = "default"; /* sizeof(string) == strlen("default")+1 */
    printf("The default String is: %s\n", string); 
    //^ you want the array to decay to a char* here
    /*scanf("%s", &string); -- DANGEROUS 
    -- scanf doesn't know how much space you have in string*/

    fgets(string /*decay again*/,  sizeof(string), stdin);
    /* fgets does know because you've told it with sizeof(string)*/

    chomp(string, '\n');
    printf("You entered: %s", string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although uncommon, after `fgets()`, `string[0]` may be 0 and `l = strlen(s); s[l-1]` is a problem.  Defensive coding insures the first character after `fgets()` was not a user entered null character.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution:

```
char string[20];
strcpy(string, "default");  
printf("The default String is: %s", string);
scanf("%19s", string);
printf("You entered: %s", string);
```

Comment: `strcpy(string, "default");` is not necessary; `char string[20] = "default";` will work just as well.

Comment: @user694733 No. Please read my comments with Marievi

Comment: I saw your comment. It's incorrect. `char string[20]` is an array, and `= "default"` is valid initializer for it. N1570 6.7.9 p14: *"An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF −8 string
literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
elements of the array."*

Comment: @user694733 You are right. I double checked. The initializer copies. It is not a pointer assignment. So, no need for `strcpy`, the assignment would be enough

Comment: 19 in `"The default String is: %19s"` serves little value.  Missing 19 from `scanf("%s", string);` is as bad as `gets(string);`.